# Flutter does not copy assets into iOS 14 simulator?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, fluttermap, flutter-assetimage

Not sure what I am doing wrong.
I specify my assets in `pubspec.yml` like so

```
assets:
  - assets/markers/station.png
  - assets/markers/other/
  - assets/markers/files/
```

and try loading it as a marker image with flutter map:

```
child: FlutterMap(
              options: MapOptions(
                center: const LatLng(32.8150, -117.2734), // Set initial map center
                zoom: 12.0, // Set initial zoom level
                maxZoom: 16
              ),
              children: [
                TileLayer(
                urlTemplate: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'),      
                MarkerLayer(
                  markers: [
                    Marker(
                      point: const LatLng(32.8150, -117.2734),
                      builder: (ctx) => Image.asset('assets/markers/station.png'),
                      rotate: false,
                    ),
                  ],
                  rotate: false,
                )
              ],

            ),
```

but on iOS all I see is a red box at the location where the marker image should be. Using this path 'markers/station.png' works with the Chrome debugger. So the file exists at least for the web debugging.

More, I browsed to the app bundle in the simulator and the `Documents` folder is empty. Per documentation I understand this is where my markers should end up

`path/to/app/bundle/Documents/assets/...`

but `Documents` is empty. I see no errors during app build regarding path conflicts.
Also, I did

```
$ flutter clean
$ flutter pub get
```

to rebuild the app bundle but still no assets copied? Can anyone please suggest what to do? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code. You've mistakenly wrote `marker` instead of `markers`.

```
        Marker(
          point: const LatLng(32.8150, -117.2734),
          builder: (ctx) => Image.asset("assets/markers/station.png"),
          rotate: false,
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch, that is correct. It now works in Chrome using `markers/station.png` but still fails to load in the iOS simulator. Added edits to original post

Comment: But this is the real question here: any idea where the assets should be copied into the iOS app bundle? I think they are missing.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that i had the asset directive outside of the flutter directive so assets were never copied.

Found it in another post.
Needs to be

```
flutter:
  - assets:
    - assets/markers/station.png
```